# imagecreatefromstring(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Premature end of JPEG file

Tags: php, image, gd

Hello guys i have the following error:

> imagecreatefromstring(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error:
>   Premature end of JPEG file

With the following Images:
[image]

[image]

I am using the following code:

```
imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($str));
```

I found that this error only appears with large image dimensions.

I have tried to re-size the image to 1027*768 and it worked perfectly but i don't want to re-size the image.

Also i have tried the following code:

```
@imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($str));
```

It worked, but the images screwed up

[image]
[image]

Is there any idea for solving this problem and thanks.

Comment: How are you getting the data into '$str' i.e. where is the data coming from and what code is base_64 encoding it?

Comment: ob_start();
imagejpeg(...);
$c = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return base64_encode($c);
$str = base64_decode($c);

the problem is in the createfromstring, because i tried to load the base in html image and it is worked perfectly

Comment: i send the base64 to mysql table then select it from another file, the base64 code is completely good.

Comment: Try doing strlen() before and after you have saved and loaded the image to and from in the database.

Comment: i already tried, its the same 100%

Comment: when i try <img src='data:image/png;base64,....' /> its works normally, the problem is in imagecreatefromstring

Comment: How weird - you've seen this http://worcesterwideweb.com/2008/03/17/php-5-and-imagecreatefromjpeg-recoverable-error-premature-end-of-jpeg-file/ ? What version of PHP are you on?

Comment: yeah i have seen it didn't work for me, php 5.4.14 under IIS 8

Comment: Just for debugging purposes try setting php memory to infinite. ini_set('memory_limit','-1'); I think it has to do with it not having enough memory load all the string into memory while drawing it.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention in your comment, you send the base64 to a mysql table, and as mentioned, the data before and after is 100% the same, ruling out the possibily that your mysql field is not large enough (although you could check to be sure).

Since you are using ob_start() and ob_get_contents(), it could be an output buffer related issue (max buffer size / output buffer handlers etc.), so i would suggest rewriting the code to use a (temporary) output file in imagejpeg() first and checking the results with that setup

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was trying to get data from user inputed image.

The problem was that I stored the base64 coded string in to **input** field.
There might be some kind of limit how much data input field can hold.

I used **textarea** instead of input field and my code worked just fine!

Try  this one:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // Get data from textarea
    $data = $_POST['image'];
    $data = explode("base64,", $data);
    // Decode the string
    $data = base64_decode($data[1]);

    $im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
    if ($im !== false) {
        // Saves file
        imagejpeg($im, 'image.jpg');
        imagedestroy($im);
    }
    else {
        // Show errors
        echo 'An error occurred.'; 
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<img src="" id="image-preview" style="width: 400px;" alt="">

<form action="" method="post">
    <textarea name="image" id="image"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Make Image">
</form>

<input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Get's the data from file field and shows it in img tag
    function PreviewImage() {
        var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

        oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
            document.getElementById("image-preview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
            $("textarea").text(oFREvent.target.result);
        };
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and it turns out increasing the php ini setting for memory_limit solved it.

The memory_limit was set to 32 MB but when I increased it to 500 MB the problem went away.  Which is a little bit strange because the file I couldn't upload was only 2 MB but imagecreatefromstring clearly uses a lot more memory than just the file size.